# Complex-analytic argument that $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acts isometrically on $\mathbb H^2 \subseteq \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb H^2 := \left\{ z = x+iy \in \mathbb C : y > 0\right\}$, equipped with the hyperbolic Riemannian metric $\breve{g} = \frac 1{y^2}\left(dx^2 + dy^2\right)$. It is a classical result that the group $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acts on $\mathbb H^2$ isometrically via 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{array}\right) \cdot z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}
$$
Denote $\theta_A(z) = A\cdot z$ for $A \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$. Then it is straightforward to calculate
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\theta_A(z) = \frac 1{(cz+d)^2}. 
$$
**Problem:** Find a complex-analytic proof using $\frac{d}{dz}\theta_A(z)$ to show $\theta_A : \mathbb H^2 \to \mathbb H^2$ is an isometry.

I have the following argument in *real* Cartesian coordinates: $\theta_A$ becomes $\theta_A(x,y) = \big( u(x,y),\: v(x,y)\big)$, where
$$
u(x,y) = \frac{(ax+b)(cx+d)+acy^2}{(cx+d)^2+c^2y^2},\qquad v(x,y) = \frac y{(cx+d)^2+c^2y^2}
$$
Since $\theta_A : \mathbb H^2 \to \mathbb H^2$ is a holomorphic function, $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so the differential of the map $\theta_A : \mathbb H^2 \to \mathbb H^2$ (considering $\mathbb H^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$) satisfies: 
\begin{align*}
d(\theta_A)_z &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
v_y & -v_x \\ v_x & v_y
\end{array}\right) \\
&= \frac 1{\left((cx+d)^2+c^2y^2\right)^2}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
(cx+d)^2-c^2y^2 & 2cy(cx+d) \\ -2cy(cx+d) & (cx+d)^2 - c^2 y^2
\end{array}\right) 
\end{align*}
Therefore if we let $\left\{ \partial_x, \partial_y\right\}$ denote the standard coordinate frame induced by the identity coordinates $\mathbb H^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^2$, it's a starightforward calculation to show 
$$
\theta_A^*\breve g(\partial_x, \partial y) = 0, \qquad \theta_A^* \breve g(\partial_x, \partial_x) = \theta_A^* \breve g(\partial_y, \partial_y) = \frac 1{y^2},
$$
whence it follows that $\theta_A^* \breve{g} = \breve{g}$, so $\theta_A$ is a Riemannian isometry.

*However:* I'm trying to develop comfort and familiarity with complex one-forms and Riemannian geometry of complex surfaces, so I would like to know what the details would be in order to use $\theta_A'(z) = (cz+d)^{-2}$ to show $\theta_A$ is an isometry, without falling back to Cartesian coordinates. I'd also like to avoid using geodesics if possible, in favor of using complex differential forms and complex coordinate frames (i.e. $\left\{ dz, d\overline z\right\}$ and $\left\{\partial/\partial z, \partial/\partial\overline z\right\}$ respectively). Any insights on what this flavor of argument would look like?

**EDIT:** See comments for a solution.

Comment: Instead of pulling back $dx\otimes dx + dy\otimes dy$ you can pull back $dz\otimes d\bar z$ working just with the complex derivative.

Comment: @TedShifrin Would I be correct in understanding (a) that $dz \otimes d\overline z = dz\,d\overline z = dx^2 + dy^2$ and (b) that $\{dz,d\overline z\}$ is a coframe to $\{\partial/\partial z, \partial/\partial\overline z\}$ in your comment?

Comment: $\frac{d |z|}{\Im(z)}$ is $\gamma \in SL_2(\Bbb{R})$-invariant because $d\gamma(z) = \gamma'(z) dz = \frac{dz}{(cz+d)^{2}}$ and $\Im(\gamma(z)) = \frac{\Im(z)}{|cz+d|^2}$ so $\frac{d |\gamma(z)|}{\Im(\gamma(z))} = \frac{|\gamma'(z)| d|z|}{\Im(\gamma(z))} =\frac{d |z|}{\Im(z)}$. The distance on the manifold is $D(u,v) = \min_{\lambda: u \to v} \int_\lambda \frac{d|z|}{\Im(z)}$ and $\gamma \circ \lambda$ is a geodesic iff $\lambda$ is a geodesic.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808211/proving-that-a-map-is-an-isometry?rq=1

Comment: Officially, to make it a symmetric tensor you should do $\frac12(dz\otimes d\bar z + d\bar z\otimes dz)$, but people tend to do just $|dz|^2$. :P

Comment: I think tying together what everyone is saying, if $\theta_A(z) = w = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, then $\overline w = \frac{a\overline z + b}{c\overline z + d}$, and $dw = \frac{dz}{(cz+d)^2}$, so $d\overline w = \frac{d\overline z}{(c\overline z + d)^2}$. Since $ad-bc=1$, we can show $\mathrm{Im}(w) = \mathrm{Im}(z)/|cz+d|^2$. In these coordinates, $\breve g = dz\,d\overline z/\mathrm{Im}(z)$. So, $$\theta_A^*\breve{g} = \frac{dw\,d\overline w}{\mathrm{Im}(w)^2} = \frac{|cz+d|^4}{\mathrm{Im}(z)^2} \frac{dz\,d\overline z}{|cz+d|^4} = \frac{dz\,d\overline z}{\mathrm{Im}(z)^2} = \breve{g}.$$